# How to add some text after the text in the span using jquery?

Tags: jquery, tags, html

I want to insert some text after the text in the span as follows. I want add the &times after Tag1 like "Tag 1 &times". But it the &times is after the `</span>`, which means outside the span. Thanks.

BTY, is there any good suggestion for the delete button for the tags?

html:

```
<li><span>Tag 1</span></li>
```

jquery:

```
$('li span').append('<p>&times</p>');
```

Comment: seems to work fine here - it inserts it after the text and before the `</span>` http://jsfiddle.net/XKzrx/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var span = $('li span');
span.html(span.html() + '&times');
```

Is this what you're looking for?

If you want to do it in one line:

```
$(that).find('span')[0].innerHTML += '&times';
```

Comment: That's correct. But I want add it into one function like this $(that).find('span').html($(that).find('span').html()+ '&times'),it doesn't work, could you tell me the reason? Thanks

Comment: What is the context and why are you against setting one variable and reusing that? Updated my answer to include a possible way to do it.

Comment: I want to add some tags to a tagContainer when I click the tag list. And the list is as <li><span>Hobby</span></li>. So I want the list with no &times, but let the &times appear in the tagContainer. Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and maybe I can get a better idea of what you're asking?

Comment: The &times sign doesn't work very well. It will stay there after I delete the tag.

Comment: Give this a try: http://jsfiddle.net/BgkBU/5/ I'm cloning the `<span>` and adding the `&times` to the innerHTML of it before appending.

Comment: That works great. Thx!!! BTY, could you recommend some materials on jquery, php and other web languages? I am a fresher, so much to be learned...@kalley

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li span').after('&times');
```